# Are JavaScript cookies created inside functions or can be created just inside the script itself?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a really confusing question as a beginner in JavaScript. So I was told to create a cookie counter, so I wanted to know if you can create the cookie within the `<script>` itself or I should include it inside a function.

```
<script>
  document.document.cookie="username=John Doe";
</script>
```

OR

```
<script>
  function x(){
  document.cookie="username=John Doe";
  }
</script>
```

And one more thing, I was able to simply copy a program and run it correctly, but can you suggest a simple way to do hit counter using cookies?

Thank you so much!

Comment: How you organize the code is completely up to you. Do you want to execute that statement only once on page load? No need for a function. Do you plan to execute that statement multiple times while the user is on the webpage? Put it in a function and call it whenever you want.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm. You can do it either ways. If you use inside a function, and call that, it should execute correctly. In the script tag as well, it will execute correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be needing to frequently set the cookie Username to "John Doe" a lot, then keep it inside a function and use that function instead. This way it'll make it a lot easier to refactor your code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the cookie part of your javascript however you should put it in a function so it can be called from your `html` event like this:

**HTML**

```
<body onload="someFunction()">
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function someFunction(){
  document.cookie="username=John Doe";
  }
```